# Stuck on trivial proof show $(I - A)$ is non singular if $\|A\| < 1$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, normed-spaces

Assume $A$ is square, $\|A\| < 1$

Attempt: (by contradiction)

Suppose $I - A$ is singular, then there exists $x$ such that $x \neq 0$, $\|x\| > 0$, $(I - A)x = 0$

Then $\|(I - A)x\| = 0$ and $\|Ix - Ax\| \geq | \|x\| - \|Ax\|$|

But here we do not know $\|Ax\|$, so we cannot claim 
$| \|x\| - \|Ax\| > 0$ to obtain a contradiction...

Does anyone know how to carry on from this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that there exists an $x\neq 0$ such that $(I-A)x = 0$. Assume without loss of generality that $\|x\| = 1$. Then $\|Ax\| = \|x\| = 1$. Hence, $\|A\| = \max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\| \geq 1$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\| (I-A)x \| = \| x - Ax \| \geq \| x \| - \| A x \| \geq \| x \| - \| A \| \| x \|$$

The first inequality is the "reverse triangle inequality". It follows from the standard triangle inequality, because

$$x=(x-Ax)+Ax \Rightarrow \| x \| \leq \| x - Ax \| + \| Ax \|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(I - A)(\sum_n A^n)=(\sum_n A^n) (I - A)=I$ Note that $\|A\| < 1$ implies $\sum_n A^n$ converges